# Ordered probit and generalized ordered probit estimates

Tags: regression, econometrics, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I have a four-level ordinal variable as my dependent variable. In the regression table, I have the ordered probit (oprobit) estimates in the first column and the generalized ordered probit (goprobit) estimates in the second, third and fourth columns. I am doing this because the parallel trends assumption does not hold and I want to compare both methods.

I have two questions:

1. How can the oprobit coefficient be interpreted relative to the goprobit models? Does it make any sense, for example, to say that it is the effect of increasing one unit of X on increasing Y in one "weighted" level? By "weighted" I mean taking into account the number of observations that responded in each level.
2. I have one variable for which none of the goprobit estimates is significant, but the one that comes from the oprobit is significant. How can I interpret this result?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Say a bit about what generalized ordered probit means.  I assume it is like the partial proportional odds model in which the proportional odds assumption is relaxed for selected covariates.

Comment: Yes! The difference is that, in the partial model, only the variables that don't pass the brant test show different coefficients for every level. In the generalized model, the brant test is not ran, so all the variables have a different coefficient for every level of the ordered variable.

Comment: Now I'm worried.  The Brant test (really the Peterson-Harrell test, 1990) is anti-conservative, i.e., it rejects the parallelism assumption too often.  See [this](https://fharrell.com/post/impactpo) for better ways of thinking about the parallelism assumption.  And it is not good statistical practice to base model selection on a p-value.  What software did that?

Comment: I ultimately did not use the test. With the goprobit I'am showing all the coefficients for all the levels. Still, my questions remain.

Comment: Either model can be used to estimate probabilities for all levels of Y.  I'd probability interpret them through these probabilities.  Or compute Y-specific effects on the linear predictors scale.  For a partial proportional odds model you would add the main log odds ratio and the incremental log odds ratio for a specific Y cutoff.